# Before page refresh the same email id has to be there in second form when we click on forgot button

Tags: codeigniter, pgp

[when we select forgot after giving email id in the first image it has to display the same email id even in second image without refreshing the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjifY.png)

[As i told, if i refresh the page email is getting in the field but i need that before page refresh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XcC9.png)

**controller code**
public function ResetPassword() {

```
    $emaill = $this->input->post('emaill');
    $otp = $this->input->post('otp');

  //$this->form_validation->set_rules('emaill', 'emaill', 'required|min_length[10]|max_length[30]|matches[otp]');
     $this->form_validation->set_rules('otp', 'otp', 'required|min_length[6]|max_length[6]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('newpassword', 'newpassword', 'trim|required|max_length[15]|min_length[8]|alpha_numeric|matches[confirmpassword]');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirmpassword', 'Confirm password', 'trim|required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('login');
    } else {


        if($this->session->userdata('otp') == "$otp" && $this->session->userdata('findemaill') == "$emaill" ) {
            $user = $this->session->userdata('findemaill');
            $this->load->model('Login_model');
            $result['data'] = $this->Login_model->resetpassword($user);

            $result['data1'] = $this->Login_model->resetpasswordd($user);
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success_msg', 'successfull reset the password');
            $this->load->view('login');

       } 


    }

}
```

**Model code**

```
public function resetpassword($user) {


        $new_password = $this->input->post('newpassword');
        $this->db->set('password',$new_password);
        $this->db->where('email',$user );
        $this->db->update('supplier_registration');
}
 public function resetpasswordd($user) {
       $new_password = $this->input->post('newpassword');
        $this->db->set('password',$new_password );
        $this->db->where('email',$user);
        $this->db->update('customer_registration'); 

    }
```

**View page**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/ResetPassword" method="POST">
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <input type="text" name="emaill" id="emaill" placeholder="Enter your Mobile/Email Address" value="<?php echo $this->session->userdata('findemaill'); ?>" autocomplete="off" id="forgot-email"/>

    </div>

    <div class="field-wrap">
        <input type="text" name="otp" id="otp" placeholder="Enter OTP" value="<?php echo set_value('otp'); ?>"/>
         <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('otp'); ?></span>
    </div>
      <?php    echo $this->session->flashdata('passwordmissmatch'); ?>
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <input type="text" name="newpassword" id="newpassword" placeholder="Enter new Password" value="<?php echo set_value('newpassword'); ?>"/>
          <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('newpassword'); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="field-wrap">
        <input type="text" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" placeholder="Re-enter new Password" value="<?php echo set_value('confirmpassword'); ?>"/>
         <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('confirmpassword'); ?></span>
    </div>

    <div class="field-wrap">
        <button type="submit" name="resubmit" id="resubmit" class="btn btn-submit">submit</button>
    </div>
<?php    echo $this->session->flashdata('success_msg'); ?>



    <div class="field-wrap">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn-show-login btn btn-link btn-nobg" >Back</a>
    </div>

</form>
```

**forgot page link form**

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Index.php/Login_cntrl/login" method="POST" >

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <label class="view-label">Email Address</label>
                            <input type="email" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" id="email" class="input-control" value="<?php echo set_value('email'); ?>"/>
                           <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" value="<?php echo set_value('password'); ?>" />
                            <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>

                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-forgot" >Forgot ?</a>  

                        </div>


                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-submit" name="ulogin" id="ulogin" >Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field-wrap">
                            <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-link btn-nobg" id="btn-show-signup">NEW User? Sign up</a>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

Comment: use jquery, when user click on **forgot** link, then get email and generate link like `www.example.com?email=EMAIL` and redirect to next page by `window.location`

Comment: i am not getting plz send me the code

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery for this:

```
$('.forgotLink').click(function (e) {
       e.preventDefault();
       window.location = $(this).attr('href') + '?email=' + encodeURIComponent($('#email').val());
    });
```

Comment: I tried your code. But, it is not working properly as per my requirement

Comment: my requirement is without refresh the page first form email id after click the forgot link it should display  same email id in second form

Comment: your both form are on the same page or other separate page?

Comment: separate form,two forms shown in above please go through

Comment: my above will fulfill you requirement, in your ResetController method just use `$email = $this->input->get('email');` which will fetch the email from url and then pass into your view like `$this->load->view('reset',$email');` and echo in input email box `value="<?php echo $email; ?>"`. hope you understand

Comment: undefined variable email like that error showing in second form